# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError varaible Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following template element:

```
  <input
   class="form-check-input"
   type="radio"
   name="radio_{{ id }}"
   id="{{ id }}">
```

And component is:

```
  import * as uuid from 'uuid';
  public get id(): number {
       return uuid.v4();
  }
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
> has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
> '103cb048-c966-4b76-b795-31dd2234204c'. Current value:

The component has default strategy.

> 'a04eba4a-06b6-400b-af6c-e9afe3040919'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every change detection cycle, it will call the `id()` getter, and thus generating a new id. This is most likely not correct, because it will also cause the `id` and `name` attribute to be different on the input. I think you are looking for this:

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
  
public id: string = uuid.v4();
```

I can however advice you to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy, as it will give your application a performance boost. As well as making the change detection more logical

Comment: What if I have merthod in component that return boolean and tempolate is: `<div *ngIf="isVisibleField(field)">`. Is it bad practice too?

Comment: @Mamkad: If you are using default CD strategy, yes. The function `isVisibleField()` will also be triggered for each CD cycle.

Comment: @Mamkad yes it is bad practice if you are calling an method from template, That will trigger an additional change detection and you are not aware of that how many times it is going re-render

Comment: @Mamkad actually, calling a function from template is not entirely bad practice. If the method is small, and has no side-effects, it has no noticeable performance difference. That's because every expression inside your template will already be converted to a function and it will increase readability of your template. As long as the return value doesn't change during a detection cycle, it's all good.

Comment: How then check if field has another visible status ti show/hide?